# How do I merge 2 files if a different column in each file match and both files are in csv/double quote separated formats?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I've got 2 csv/double quote separated files. Column 26 in file 1 and column 2 in file 2 both contain domains and if I run the following

```
awk -F'"' '{print $26}' file1.csv
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' file2.txt
```

Then I can see that file 1 has 6 domains and file 2 has 3 domains.

All of the domains in file 2 are also in file 1.

I'd like to generate a new file containing of all columns in file 1 plus all of the columns in file 2 if column 2 in file 2 matches column 26 in file 1.

Also, I'm pretty sure that column 26 is always the last column in file 1 but file 2 can have any number of columns.

Does anyone know how can I do this in bash, awk, sed or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bruce: Try:

```
awk -F'"' 'FNR==NR{A[$26]=$0;next} ($2 in A){print A[$2] FS $0}' file1  file2
```

So here I am checking FNR==NR condition which will be TRUE only when first file file1 is being read, then creating an array named A whose index is $26 field and setting it's value to current line and putting next will skip all further statements. Then checking $2 of file2 is present in file1's array A then printing the array A's value with current line's value.

Kindly provide sample Input_file and expected output in case above doesn't meet your requirements .